# SharePoint Online Date Picker Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I have created custom list in SharePoint Online. In new SharePoint Look for column I have selected date and time. In list add form it shows time as drop down but 30 minute interval. How can I change that? I want time with 5 minute interval or user can pick any time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to modify in SharePoint Online to change the interval in date/time column. However, this can be achieved through customization by using the SharePoint object model or in below work around.

Creating a Date field, then creating a Choice field for Hour including values 0 - 23, and a Choice field for Hour including values 0 - 59. Then creating a custom New Form and manipulating the table to place the Minute and Hour fields next to the date field. It now looks like a DateTime field, but with 1 minute increments or as per your customization.

Comment: In new look of SharePoint Online form we cannot modify add/edit form. To modify add/edit form we have to switch to classic view. But I do not want to switch to classic view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bug in SPO, however this happens only the new/edit item form. If you try to edit the date/time column in the quick edit mode, I was able to get the 5 min interval. Check below screenshot:

[image]

But for now, I dont think we have a solution for new/edit form as MS has disabled customizations on the modern lists/libraries.

You can raise a uservoice request - [SPO uservoice](http://sharepoint.uservoice.com/)